# Practical implementation of state observer

Tags: control, control-system

The state observer uses the measurements of the input and the output to provide an estimated of the system states. Let us assume that we have a controlled plant. Now, the output of the controller is a control signal. The control signal will go to the plant, as well as it will go to the state observer, so that the states of the system can be estimated. My question is: How can the same control signal go to the plant also and state observer also? Wont, it be divided into two parts , as it is going to two different places (plant and observer)? How can the same signal go to both the places?

Comment: what about voltage? ... would voltage be divided? ... what about digital signals? ... would they cease to be digital?

Comment: An observer is a model of the system, which makes the estimated states available for feedback to the controller. It's useful when the actual system states are inaccessible to measurement.

Comment: i'll suggest you to read ieee research  paper by DAVID G. LUENBERGER ,he beautifully explained  how observers work .here is link to download                                     https://sci-hub.tw/10.1109/TAC.1971.1099826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't be simpler: For example you power the device with mains power (output) and you measure the current/voltage with a DMM (observer).

EDIT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpdnzm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

@ShiS Current/Voltage is just an example, the controller outputs a value let's say u(t) and gets a feedback value, let's say y(t). The observer's input values are both u(t) and y(t).

The signals can be routed inside the controller, where both control and observer are implemented, y(t) is measured with ADC and u(t) is output to DAC.

If the observer is a different black box, then it can have two ADCs to measure y(t) and u(t), then those values have to be normalized, to have the same units as controller.

The observer can also have no measurement ADC, the signals u(t) and y(t) could be sent from the controller to the observer via a communication link.

If this observer is an analog computing device, then it can simply buffer the u(t) and y(t) with an opamp.

Comment: How can an observer measure the current. Typically, Observer is a computer based program that takes the control signal as one of the input. So, how can the same control signal be going to plant input as well as an observer input?

Comment: Voltage is normally the quantity measures but, basic current sensing is done with very small value resistors or some type of magnetic based sensor.

Comment: Let us for a moment forget the voltage and current. My query is: How can the same control signal go the observer as well as the plant. I mean signal is one particular physical thing. How can it go to both places

Comment: A *duplicate* copy of the control signal is sent to the observer. Duplicate can be made either by copying the variable holding the control value (digital control) or by connecting a voltage follower buffer (continuous control).

Answer (score 1):

Most analog linear systems are implement using opamps with high input impedance and high output current/low output impedance.

You could directly buffer the control signal if you wanted but it's assumed that your control signal provider can supply what ever current is needed.